# Formalizing the idea of "algorithm"

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, logic

I have encountered  several times, while doing mathematics, the following
situation: We have a finite  "sequence" $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$
of some objects that has the (meta-mathematical) property that the
value of $p$ isn't known beforehand - and we get it only if we " run''/''compile''
the  "sequences" $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$
(hence the use of the " ", since this  "sequence" isn't
well defined if its domain isn't know at the time of its definition). So this is actually an algorithm, since in algorithm there also a "runtime" also doesn't have to be specified at the beginning.

1. How can we get around this difficulty, i.e. how can we rigorously
   define $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ ?

   I
   always thought that we translate the  "sequences" $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$
   to another mathematical object for which one doesn't need to specify
   how "long'' it can run. For example I could mimick one step
   of $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ by a function
   $f$, such that $a_{2}=f(a_{1}),\ a_{3}=\left(f\circ f\right)\left(a_{1}\right)$
   and so on and let $f$ attain some specific value $\alpha$, if the iteration
   wasn't succesful for. Then I could just define my $p$ as the smallest
   number such that $f$ equals $\alpha$ - and now I could rigorously
   define $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$.
2. Is the above idea correct ? Do you know of other such methods ?
3. There are of course algorithms such that only knowing the input
   there is a closed expression (involving only certain function - not
   arbitrary ones like my $f$ above) that tells me, how long my algorithm
   will run, but I don't think that that is the case for all algorithms.
   Is that true ? Can someone contribute something interesting ? (I know,
   I'm going slightly off-topic here).
4. Is there an area in mathematics that deals with questions like
   1.-2. ? Maybe proof theory? What about questions like 3. ?

Note: If you should ask me for examples of such "sequences"
$\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ : The euclidean
algorithm, the greedy algorithm for a minimal spanning tree of graph...actually
take any maths book that contains the word "algorithm", since
a (well-defined) algorithm is nothing but a finite sequence, for
which we generally don't know yet, how long it will run (I haven't checked,
if for these two algorithms there is a simple closed expression in
terms of "classic'' functions, that determine beforehand how
long they run...if there is, pretend you don't know it and have to
take the route described in 1. to get your number of iterations until the algorithm terminates )

Comment: Would reading [Aho, Hopcroft & Ullman](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201000237) help?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sadly no. I just browsed through in at the concept of algorithm isn't formalized there

Comment: Sorry, I think that the standard formalization of an algorithm is something that a [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) can perform, and had a vague recollection that the concept would be explained in that book.

Comment: It looks like you're using the word "algorithm" with a somewhat different meaning than the one it usually has in mathematics. Certainly the claim "a (well-defined) algorithm is nothing but a finite sequence" does not at all describe the usual meaning of "algorithm".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry for getting back so late. Indeed, it seems that my notation of an algorithm is a different one that usually accepted (is the usual notion of an algorithm something a Turing Machine can perfom, as Lahtinen indicated ?). But how is my notation different then the usual one ?

Comment: @temo: Yes, an algorithm is something a Turing machine can do. Your use of the word seems to be so different from that that I cannot see any similarity in meaning at all -- and thus I have no idea where to begin explaining "how are they different".

Comment: It seems like you're unhappy with the idea of a sequence that we don't know the length of.  Such a sequence is still perfectly fine.  For example, consider the sequence of twin primes.  It might be finite, or it might be infinite.  We don't know.  But that doesn't mean that the sequence doesn't exist!

Answer (score 3):

> How can we get around this difficulty, i.e. how can we rigorously define $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ ?
>
> I always thought that we translate the  "sequences"
>   $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ to another
>   mathematical object for which one doesn't need to specify how "long''
>   it can run. For example I could mimick one step of
>   $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ by a function
>   $f$, such that $a_{2}=f(a_{1}),\ a_{3}=\left(f\circ
> > f\right)\left(a_{1}\right)$ and so on and let $f$ attain some specific
>   value $\alpha$, if the iteration wasn't succesful for. Then I could
>   just define my $p$ as the smallest number such that $f$ equals
>   $\alpha$ - and now I could rigorously define
>   $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$.

What you've described is the basic idea of Turing Machine. A Turing Machine transforms one tape state ($a_n$) to another tape state ($a_{n+1}$) according to a fixed and finite-sized state transitions table ($f$ is well defined given any valid tape state and head state, except for the terminal states) and an internal state of the head.

It should be noted that the hypothetical Turing Machine have an infinite length tape, however due to physical limitations, real-life computers always have a finite amount of RAM to work with (real life computers are only a [Linear-bounded automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton), which is strictly weaker than Turing Machine due to the lack of infinite memory).

You could define the sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,p\right\} }$ such that $a_k$ is the state of the Turing Machine at time $k$.

---

> Is the above idea correct ? Do you know of other such methods ?

As for alternative formulations, there are [Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [μ-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function). It was later proven that even though they look very different from the outset, they were actually computationally equivalent to the Turing Machine (i.e. what is computable in a Turing Machine is computable in Lambda Calculus and μ-recursive functions and vice versa).

There are also computation models that are NOT computationally equivalent to Turing Machine, for example, the Finite State Machine and Pushdown Automata; these models are strictly weaker than the Turing Machine (i.e. there are algorithms that can be computed in a Turing Machine that cannot be computed on these machines).

---

> There are of course algorithms such that only knowing the input there is a closed expression (involving only certain function - not
>   arbitrary ones like my $f$ above) that tells me, how long my algorithm
>   will run, but I don't think that that is the case for all algorithms.
>   Is that true ? Can someone contribute something interesting ? (I know,
>   I'm going slightly off-topic here).

I think you should read about the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), excerpt from Wikipedia:

> In computability theory, the halting problem can be stated as follows: "**Given a description of an arbitrary computer program, decide whether the program finishes running or continues to run forever**". This is equivalent to the problem of deciding, given a program and an input, whether the program will eventually halt when run with that input, or will run forever.
>
> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that **a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist**. A key part of the proof was a mathematical definition of a computer and program, what became known as a Turing machine; the halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines. It is one of the first examples of a decision problem.

In other words, Alan Turing proved that **it is not always possible to know how long the program will run given a certain input**.

---

> Is there an area in mathematics that deals with questions like
>   1.-2. ? Maybe proof theory? What about questions like 3. ?

Computer Science, in general, or more specifically Computability Theory (a.k.a. Recursion Theory). There are also areas of [undecidable problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a class (set) of objects and consider the class (set) of finite sequences with members in C. We can refer to the latter class as $C^*$. Each $s\in C^*$ is a finite (possibly empty) sequence of elements of type $C$. Just as the class of natural numbers "comes with" a "built-in" successor operator that takes a number $n$ and returns the number $n+1$, so does our class $C^*$ come with two built-in operators: the length operator $\ell$, returning for each $s\in C^*$ $s$'s length $s.\ell$ and an index operator, taking an element $s$ of $C^*$ and a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and returning the $s$ element (of type $C$) at the $n$th place, $s_n$ (if $s.\ell\leq n$, $s_n$ is some unspecified $C$ value, in other words in this case $s_n$ is undefined). Now, you can define, say, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ the set $C^n$ of $C$-sequences of length $n$ thus:
$$C^n:=\{s:C^*\left|:\space s.\ell=n\right.\}$$

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't an answer to my question. You gave a description of the set $C^n$, of all sequences of length $n$, taken from a bigger set $C^*$. But my question was: Given just one (fixed) algorithm (or equivalently a finite "sequence", for which we don't know, when it will stop), how can I translate this algorithm into a welldefined mathematical object.

Comment: Are you wondering how an algorithm can tell the length of a sequence of data? How about introducing an EOF ("End of File") symbol to indicate the end of the input? If you are reluctant to introduce a new symbol into the alphabet, encode the extended alphabet using the original one.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. I don'T think introducing and EOF symbol to terminate the input is what I had in mind. My problem is not that I don't know when the input terminates; it's that given some input, I don't know when the algorithm terminates (and this is something nontrivial - consider for example the Collatz conjecture which essentially says that a specific algorithm always terminates; proving this is so difficult that it is still an open problem)

Comment: In most formal definitions of algorithm must always have a "terminating condition", i.e. a condition that when reached will mark the end of the algorithm, e.g. when a certain character is found in the sequence (e.g. EOF or your α). A sequence of steps that does not have a terminating condition is usually called computational method/computational process.